# How to make a decimal with comma instead dot for input number in html5 in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I would like a  that accept comma instead of dot

Using a validator like below works in chrome but not in edge :

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?" name="my-num"
    step="0.01"
    id="with-validator"/>

$('#with-validator').on('change keyup', function(event) {
    if ( event.target.validity.valid ) {
        $('#result').text($(this).val());
    } else {
        $('#result').text('NOPE');
    }    
});
```

Unfortunately I am working on a UWP windows 10 app that use the Edge render engine.

How could I achieve this in Edge?

Comment: localization on number input is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min=".01" max=".99" step= ".01"/>
```

This is a simpler way to right the regex expression, but as to your actual issue...

http://quirksmode.org/html5/inputs/
States that Edge only offers 3 4 and 5 out of this list
This type is supported if the browser 
1.Offers the user a customised interface (custom keyboard on touchscreen; arrows on desktop)
2.Restricts input to numbers (and related characters such as a negative sign)
3.Does not send incorrect data to the server
4.Halts form submission upon finding incorrect data
5.Informs the user of a failed submission with an error message

in a nutshell the HTML5 input number is not 100 percent supported by the edge browser